# How can I change the error messages for 'touch'?

Tags: command-line, permissions

Lets just have some typical usage of touch as expected:

```
$ touch this
$ sudo chown root this
$ touch this
touch: this: Permission denied
```

Now what I want to do is change `touch: this: Permission denied` to say `Can't touch this.`

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You can (1) patch and recompile `touch` or (2) write a wrapper around it which reads the original error messages and outputs something different instead.

Comment: http://www.radford.edu/~ibarland/Public/OldHumor/unix

Comment: An easy way of doing (2) would be to specify the following alias in your `.bash_aliases` file or equivalent, since you seem to be using Debian or a derivative: `alias touch="touch 2>&1 | sed \"s/touch: \(.*\): Permission denied/You can\'t touch \1./g\""`

Answer (score 3):

Get `touch`'s source code, find the *Permission Denied* message, replace it by what you want, recompile and there you go.